# Compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH different than the one specified with -ccbin

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cuda, icc

This is on Windows 7 Pro 64 bit with CUDA 6.5 and Intel Composer 2015, in Visual Studio 2013.

I have a project that contains a mix of native c++ and CUDA.  I'm trying to switch from the Microsoft compiler to the Intel compiler, for better vectorization and performance.  However, I can't get the project to build after installing Intel Composer and changing the project setting to use the Intel compiler.

Whenever I try to build, I get the error:

```
nvcc fatal   : Compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH different than the one specified with -ccbin
```

I tried changing the compiler to the Intel compiler located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE 2015\bin\intel64, by adding

```
-ccbin C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE 2015\bin\intel64\icl.exe
```

but that errors with

```
nvcc fatal   : redefinition of argument 'compiler-bindir'
```

How can I configure CUDA to use the Intel compiler instead of the Microsoft one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the microsoft cl.exe compiler is supported on Windows.  The supported platforms are indicated in [the windows getting started document](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/index.html#system-requirements).

The intel compiler is supported as the host compiler [on linux](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#system-requirements) however.

Comment: At one point, I did manage to have CUDA and Intel playing nicely together, but then Visual Studio choked and had to be repaired.  I think the toolkits were installed in exactly the right sequence.  Oh well.....